# .trigger("change") page keep reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to display the selected value of select drop down on change in the `span`. It works, but page keep refreshing. Using `trigger` change but it keep reloading the page.

```
jQuery("select").change(function (e) {
  var str = "";
  str = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").text();   
  jQuery(".labelChanged").text(str);
}).trigger('change')
e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Can you add some code example?

Comment: jQuery("select").change(function (e) {
            var str = "";
            str = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").text();

            jQuery(".labelChanged").text(str);

        })
            .trigger('change')
            e.preventDefault();

Comment: I think you need to use `window.location.href` and set it to the new page you want to navigate to when an item is selected. It's entirely not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: i currently display select drop down default value in span as a label and on change it should update the span that it is doing yes page also refresh once to get new value but it keep refreshing

Comment: @LinkedStudio Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way. You need to provide a more complete example. It should include just enough that we can see what's happening. Sometimes it's best to move your code to a PasteBin or jsfiddle.net as a working example. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var e = document.getElementById("Sortby");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById("sortByText").innerHTML=strUser;
```